# next.js configuration to redirect all traffic to my specific path

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js app that has the following pages: `/`, `/pre-registration`, `/contest`, `/profile`, and `/auth`. I want to deploy this project on a server, but I want my users to only be able to access the `/pre-registration` page and not the other pages. If they enter the root domain, they should be redirected to the `/pre-registration` page.
What do I have to do for this purpose? which file do I have to change in my project? can I configure it on my server? Or front-end project have to change?

Comment: I'd suggest just using a middleware and just pushing users to the page for all routes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. There are several ways to address it. Adding a server.js (custom server) ruins the style of my pages due to relative paths. So, I found another way. I changed the next.config.js file as follows:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    async redirects() {
      return [
        {
          source: '/',
          destination: '/pre-registration',
          permanent: true,
        },
        {
            source: '/auth/login',
            destination: '/pre-registration',
            permanent: true,
          },
          {
            source: '/auth/signup',
            destination: '/pre-registration',
            permanent: true,
          },
          {
            source: '/profile',
            destination: '/pre-registration',
            permanent: true,
          },
          {
            source: '/contest/:path*',
            destination: '/pre-registration',
            permanent: true,
          },

      ];
    },
  };
```

As you can see, I redirected every path individually and it works. Initially, I used this code, but it gave me a connection error with the message ‘too much redirection’:

```
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
      return [
        {
          source: '/:path*',
          destination: '/pre-registration',
           permanent: true,
        },
      ];
    },
};
```